# Extract unique exact string matches on data frame column

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have (tiny subset of data with many columns)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A (quarterly) 2010': np.random.rand(3),
                   'A (quarterly) 2011': np.random.rand(3),
                   'B (quarterly) 2010': np.random.rand(3),
                   'B (quarterly) 2011': np.random.rand(3),
                   'X' : np.random.randint(3, size=3)})

#Out[11]:
#   A (quarterly) 2010  A (quarterly) 2011  B (quarterly) 2010  \
#0            0.868228            0.300513            0.658819
#1            0.383907            0.496740            0.347421
#2            0.284787            0.795499            0.856398

#   B (quarterly) 2011  X
#0            0.374479  1
#1            0.812860  0
#2            0.604731  2
```

I want to extract the unique matches in the column names that matches a specific pattern, f.ex `[A-B] \(.*\)\s`.

I can do it, but it is looks very hairy:

```
stubs = set([match[0] for match in df.columns.str.findall('[A-B] \(.*\) ').values if match != [] ])

list(stubs)
#['B (quarterly) ', 'A (quarterly) ']
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way, still somewhat hairy, but a little bit more elegant:

```
def match(x):
  m = re.findall(r'[A-B] \(.*\)\s',x)
  return m[0] if m else None

[stub for stub in df.columns.to_series().apply(match).unique() if stub]
# ['A (quarterly) ', 'B (quarterly) ']
```